# Capture the CellEditEnding event for a specific DataGridTextColumn

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I have a DataGrid where I am binding 10 DataGridTextColumn to it. I have added a CellEditEnding to capture when text is edited, so that I can save it. I was wondering if it is possible to only get the CellEditEnding for

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Notes" Binding="{Binding Path=Notes}".
```

Here is DataGrid

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" 
          BeginningEdit="OnBeginEdit" 
          CellEditEnding="OnEndEdit" 
          Name="dgActiveProblems" 
          CanUserAddRows="False" 
          CanUserDeleteRows="True" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          SelectionMode="Single"    
          AlternatingRowBackground="BlanchedAlmond"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource NormalRow}"
          IsManipulationEnabled="True" >
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Notes" Binding="{Binding Path=Notes}" Width="*">
        <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="255"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Why only this one column? Can you not use `DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs` passed to `CellEditEnding`?

Answer (score 1):

In `CellEditEnding` event handler you can check column by header:

```
private void OnEndEdit(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.Header.ToString() == "Notes")
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Saving...");
    }
}
```